# int main (int argc, char** argv) does not work in Cpp

Tags: c++

I am trying to use this simple program:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout<<"This program has "<<argc<<" arguments.";
}
```

However, the program does not get any input. It automatically puts a 1 in argc, and sth unlcear for argv!
I have also tried many different codes like:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])

int main (int argc, char *argv[])

int main (int argc, char **argv)

int main (int argc, string argv[])
```

Nothing seems to work! By the way, my compiler is DEV.

Comment: The first four options are all equivalent and valid, and the fifth one is wrong. If you didn't get any input, you didn't provide the input in the right way.

Comment: The first argument (`argv[0]`) is the name of the program, so `argc` will always be at least 1.

Comment: What input are you giving, how? Don't make people guess. Don't say things like "sth unclear" either; explain how you inspected `argv`.

Comment: Your program is working correctly, your expectations are wrong. The value of `argc` is always at least one because the program name is the first argument. (You could have tried printing the value of `argv[0]` to find out what is going on).

Comment: _"By the way, my compiler is DEV"_ That's not a known compiler. I guess you mean Devblocks IDE.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard says:

> `argc` shall be the number of arguments passed to the program from the
> environment in which the program is run. If `argc` is nonzero these
> arguments shall be supplied in `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` as
> pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated multibyte
> strings (ntmbs s) (20.4.2.1.5.2) and `argv[0]` shall be the pointer to
> the initial character of a ntmbs that represents the name used to
> invoke the program or `""`. The value of argc shall be non-negative. The
> value of `argv[argc]` shall be `0`. [ Note: It is recommended that any
> further (optional) parameters be added after argv. — end note ]

In most cases the first argument is the name of the executable. Something like `foo.exe`. The further values are typically command line arguments you pass to the application while running. So, if you run the application like:

```
foo.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The values of the variables could be:

```
argc = 4
argv = { "foo.exe", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3", NULL }
```

Do note that argv is null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you provided is the code you really have, i am wondering how it did compile, without including the iostream header. This code will work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "This program was given " << argc << " arguments." << std::endl;
}
```

When you run this code, the output will be:

```
$ nameofexecutable
This program was given 1 arguments.
```

If you give it arguments, it will print them:

```
$ nameofexecutable opt1 opt2 opt3
This program was given 4 arguments.
```

You may be wondering, why the program says it got 4 arguments while receiving only 3. That is, because the name of the executable is counted as an argument, too.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your question is why you get `argc` as 1, even if you give no arguments.
If you would do more experiments you'd notice that you always get one more than you give arguments.
This is because in most environments the first arguments `argv[0]` is filled with the executables name. You can also check that by outputting `argv[0]`.
The arguments you give on the commandline are given starting with `argv[1]`, which in the zero-based index counting world of C++ is of course the second one.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't actually provided code that exhibits your problem but, to answer your question, ways to pass argv[2] as a string to a function include

```
  #include <cstring>
  #include <iostream>
  void func(const char *s)
  {
       //  treat s as a zero terminated string

       if (std::strcmp(s, "Hello") == 0)
       {
            std::cout << "You said hello\n";
       }
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      if (argc >= 3)
        func(argv[2]);
      else
         std::cout << "You have not supplied an argv[2]\n";
  }
```

or

```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  void func2(const std::string &s)
  {
       if (s == "Hello")
       {
            std::cout << "You said hello\n";
       }
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      if (argc >= 3)
        func2(argv[2]);
      else
         std::cout << "You have not supplied an argv[2]\n";
  }
```

The first example above (apart from usage of std namespace, std::cout and C++ headers) is essentially vanilla C.

The second example uses the std::string class, so comparison of strings is possible using the == operator. Note that main(), when calling func2() implicitly converts argv[2] into an std::string (since std::string has a constructor that permits that conversion) that is then passed to the function.

In both cases, main() checks argc to ensure that 2 (or more) arguments have been passed to it.